# VPN on ubiquiti

Tags: vpn, ubiquiti

i created a VPN on a ubiquiti USG.
When i connnect, i can't ping to a server on the remote network.

The server is ip 192.168.13.15.
I get ip 192.168.100.1.
[image]

I tried to change the networks, but that doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide full sanitized configs of the Ubiquiti appliance before we can help.  There are many things it could be caused by.